# How can I populate a LiveData nested List from two different Room queries?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have two tables in my database. The first one contains the shifts of a job, with the start and end times, while the second table has the different tasks every shift has. I can get all my shifts with a query, and also I can get the tasks of a day's shift.
My goal is to merge the information of these two queries into one LiveData object to be later used in a recyclerView.
They are related n:n, a group of tasks can be repeated in different shifts throughout the months. If the shift is a day off, the tasks query would return null.

I've been searching how to get this list of shifts with their tasks but I couldn't find anything alike.
I show you the data classses I'm using:

```
/\*\* Shifts \*\*/
data class TurnosPrxTr(
var id_detalle: Long,
var id_usuario: Int,
var fecha: Long,
var turno: String,
var tipo: String,
var notas: String?,
var nombre_debe: String?,
var id_grafico: Long?,
var sitio_origen: String?,
var hora_origen: Long?,
var sitio_fin: String?,
var hora_fin: Long?,
val dia_semana: String?,
var indicador: Int?,
)

/\*\* Tasks \*\*/
data class TareaTurnoPrxTr(
var turno: String,
var id_grafico: Long?,
val dia_semana: String?,
var orden_servicio: Int,
var tipo_servicio: String?,
var sitio_origen: String?,
var hora_origen: Long?,
var sitio_fin: String?,
var hora_fin: Long?,
)

/\*\* Merging the two. This is the list I'd like to populate. \*\*/
data class TurnosConTareas(
var turno: TurnosPrxTr,
var tareas: List\<TareaTurnoPrxTr\>?
)
```

And the access to the database from a ViewModel:

```
//This query returns 30 shifts since today.
val monthShifts = database.getTurnosProximasTareas(LocalDate.now().toEpochDay())

//The three parameters this query needs are found in the shifts attributes and could be get like this:
//getTareasDeUnTurno(monthShifts.id_grafico, monthShifts.turno, monthShifts.dia_semana)
val tasksOfOneShift = database.getTareasDeUnTurno(81,"101", "L")
```

Comment: Are the first two classes your `@Entity`'s?

Comment: are the variables ```monthShifts``` and ```tasksOfOneShift``` a ```LiveData```?

Comment: Yes, they are both LiveData. The two first classes aren't entities of the DB, they come from several joins each.